# Инструмент для статического анализа кода на ANSI C

Tags: статический-анализ, c

Есть средней величины проект (~ 30 тыс. строк кода), хотелось бы найти какую-нибудь утилиту, которая съест все эти исходники и выдаст что-нибудь вроде диаграммы/графа структур, функций и их связей.

OS: Желательно GNU/Linux, но для такого дела могу и Windows расчехлить.

Comment: Нужна именно картинка или не обязательно? Поищите где-нибудь типа 
http://grok2.tripod.com/code_comprehension.html - некий обзор, сам не глядел (гугл выдал). Кстати sourcenavigator (он там указан) картинки вроде рисовал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) (статический анализ, Win, Linux, Mac) + AnalysisTool (визуализация, Mac).

Comment: Похоже то что надо, но никак не могу получить инфу. Запускаю следующее в директории с проектом:
<pre>
scan-build make
</pre>
Всё компилируется, но никаких отчётов нет:
<pre>
scan-build: Removing directory '/tmp/scan-build-2011-03-18-2' because it contains no reports.
</pre>
Пробовал с разными опциями, ничего не меняется.

Comment: А у меня работает
<pre>scan-build make
/usr/bin/ccc-analyzer -O2 -W -Wall -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -fkeep-inline-functions -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wnested-externs -Wtrigraphs    -c -o hdparm.o hdparm.c
...
ANALYZE: /usr/include/linux/swab.h __fswahw32
...
scan-build: 3 bugs found.
scan-build: Run 'scan-view /tmp/scan-build-2011-03-20-1' to examine bug reports.</pre>
Ставилось из репозитариев OpenSuse, в качестве подопытного кролика бралась hdparm с sourceforge

Answer (score 0):

UML как раз в тему, и в тему он тем боком, что многие тулзы умеют генерировать UML-диаграммы из готовых исходников. А диаграмма которую вы хотите (сущности+связи) - это одна из основных диаграмм UML.
Проблема только в том, что большинство таких тулз поддерживают в основном Java, C++. Для чистого C таких надо поискать.

Answer (score -1):

Копайте в сторону uml(которая reverse engineering). Из платных: rational rose, например. сс++java ; Из бесплатных - jdevelop: там есть плагин для работы с uml. Есть также несколько open-source программ. Посоветовать что именно - не могу, знаю только по-наслышке.

Comment: UML здесь вообще не в тему. Мне не нужно подготовить архитектуру проекта руками, мне нужно проанализировать готовый код и нарисовать примерную архитектуру, зависимости. Автоматически.